# TriggerCharacters property not working

Tags: monaco-editor

Using the monaco editor.  We have registered a custom language and completion item provider. I've also included the triggerCharacters property to get the autocomplete to pop up when the period/dot is pressed.

eg. `monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(language, {
                triggerCharacters: ["."],`

So far no luck getting it to work. Currently nothing happens at all when the period is typed.

Any suggestions of things to try?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No luck yet in getting it to work.

Comment: I got it working.

The key was the following:
1) Call registerLanguage before calling registerCompletionItemProvider.
2) Call registerLanguage *before* the editor is mounted/created.